# In C++11 can the override and final keywords be used only in the declaration and not in the definition?

Tags: c++11

It seems that `override` and `final`specifiers can be used in both declaration and definition. Is it possible to only use them at the declaration level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `override` and `final` specifiers can only appear in member definitons if the definition is inside a class definition.

*E.g.*:

```
struct Base { virtual void foo() = 0 }
struct Derived : public Base { void foo() override { std::cout << "foo"; } // OK
```

```
struct Derived : public Base { void foo() override; }
void Derived::foo() override { std::cout << "foo"; } // Error!
// ^^ Definition outside class. ^^
```

In other words, if you put the definition of a member function outside of the class definition, then *yes*, the `override` and `final` specifiers should only be present in the declaration inside the class definition.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final